# Kotlin: are companion object lateinit vars initialised once?

Tags: android, kotlin, static, companion-object, kotlin-lateinit

Given the code below:

```
class Foo {
    companion object {
        lateinit var names: Array<String>
    }
    init {
        names = arrayOf("George", "Keith", "Martha", "Margret")
    }

}
```

If I created two instances of `Foo`:

```
var foo1 = Foo();
var foo2 = Foo();
```

is `names` going to be initialised/assigned twice, and therefore with any subsequent `Foo` initialisation?

My intent is to have a simple static variable `names` holding those predefined names.

**Update:**

This is assuming I do not want to have: `var names: arrayOf("George", "Keith", "Martha", "Margret")` inside companion object.

Comment: @JeelVankhede Ive just updated my question. I knew someone would jump to that.

Comment: I assume you guys are agreeing that each time init is called, names is assigned a new instance of the array?

Comment: Yes, one other thing you can try is take your initialization to another object as local variable then use that to assign your companion variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is names going to be initialised/assigned twice, and therefore with
>   any subsequent Foo initialisation?

As in init block its initializing `names` every time so it will create new `Array` for every instance.

You can verify this with simple print

```
class Foo {
    companion object {
        lateinit var names: Array<String>
    }
    init {
        println("Creating Foo")
        names = arrayOf("George", "Keith", "Martha", "Margret")
    }

    fun getHashCode():Int{
        return names.hashCode()
    }

}

fun main() {

    var foo1 = Foo();
    println(foo1.getHashCode());
    var foo2 = Foo();
    println(foo2.getHashCode());
}
```

In Output HashCode are different :

```
Creating Foo
746292446
Creating Foo
1072591677
```

Comment: This may be even slightly clearer by moving `getHashCode` inside the `companion object`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code block to achieve what you want.

```
class Foo {

    object ArrayOfString {
        val names = arrayOf("George", "Keith", "Martha", "Margret")
    }

    companion object {
        val names: Array<String> = ArrayOfString.names
    }
}
```

By this way, you won't have initialization every time for your array, hope that make sense!

Comment: `object ArrayOfString` is a singleton in Kotlin isn't it? So this is pretty much the same as initialising `names` inside `companion object`. I think just doing that keeps it simple, as I might have over engineered a few things.

Comment: Yes, it's singleton!

Answer (score 0):

Companion object in Kotlin works same as the the static in java. By declaring a companion object inside our class, you’ll be able to call its members with the same syntax as calling static methods in Java.And yes its going to be initialized once also in kotlin we have one 
more keyword for singleton instance to create the singleton in kotlin.

On other hand init is going to called after primary constructor also you can have one or more init blocks executing in series.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Foo {
Var names :ArrayList<String> = arrayOf("George", "Keith", "Martha", "Margret")
companion object {
    lateinit var names: Array<String>
}}
```

You can do like this